# Is there a way to conditionally change main entry file in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm currently developing two applications in two different projects: a React component library to be used as a design system, and a React webapp to render pages using components from design system.

Inside my webapp, I import the components as following:

`import { Button } from 'designsystem'`

Inside the `package.json` of `designsystem`, my `main` entry points to `/src/index.js` where all my components are exported as a ES6 module. When I'm developing that's ok, because when I update a component in `designsystem` it reflects on the webapp and that's the desired behaviour.

Although when I try to build my webapp, it only works if I point the `main` entry of `designsystem` to the dist folder, which contains a bundled file with all the components as UMD. This way, I can't see the changes of the components inside my webapp unless if I build everything again.

I already tried to conditionally return the components module or dist content in `/src/index.js` in order to point to the correct content. But nothing worked.

My question is: Is there a way to conditionally change the `main` entry in `package.json`? If not, is there another solution for this?

---

**EDIT:** When the `main` is pointing to the source, I can work fine with it using `npm link`. My problem comes when I try to build the parent, unless I switch the `main` to the build folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "main" entry in your package.json deserves to point to the build folder:

> The main field is a module ID that is the primary entry point to your
>   program. That is, if your package is named foo, and a user installs
>   it, and then does require("foo"), then your main module's exports
>   object will be returned.
>
> This should be a module ID relative to the root of your package
>   folder.
>
> For most modules, it makes the most sense to have a main script and
>   often not much else.

Ref:https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main

The root of your package has nothing to do with your *dev app*. You should use [npm link](https://medium.com/@alexishevia/the-magic-behind-npm-link-d94dcb3a81af) while developing and leave unchanged your main pointing to build folder.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answer. Although even with link, if my `main` points to the build folder I'd have to run build everytime in order to affect the parent project. That's my problem.

Comment: Nope, _start_ and _build_ script are different, try to use create-react-app, eject the app and take a look at the webpack config. "npm start" make a simpler build with hot reload watching for every change, "npm build" run a more complex build with minification.

Comment: Although this is not very up-to-date (it uses webpack 3.x if I remember well) this article give a general idea on how component development has to be done: https://codeburst.io/extracting-a-react-js-component-and-publishing-it-on-npm-2a49096757f5

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'll try that way.